# Spam flag declined. Reason: how the hell is this spam?

Tags: support, spam, declined-flags

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/21721206#21721206) was flagged as spam and flag was declined:
[image]

It is obvious it's just a spam that used for promotion purposes. Cause for this answer is to create link with 'Sidsmatex Anfortech' content on the highly visited page. Note, that answer content absolutely unacceptable. Just curious:

Answers used for third-party resources promotion are not spam on SO?

Comment: That is not immediately obvious; it looks like a low-quality answer to me. The *username* is not a spam link.

Comment: There are probably hundreds of thousands answers throughout the site that link to 3rd party products that actually address the specific questions.  Do you consider them spam too?

Comment: I reviewed the user account post history, and I see **no** reason to mark the account or username as spam. The answers are perhaps low-quality, but they are on-topic and appropriate for the questions they are posted on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right, in this case seems flag must be _low-quality answer_.

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk: No, the Low Quality flag is reserved for content that you cannot make sense of. Chinese, Lorem Ipsum, a rant about the world ending, etc. It should not be used for answers, however wrong technically.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, thanks for detailed explanation :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters "the Low Quality flag is reserved for content that you cannot make sense of" ... I have *no problem at all* making sense of rants about the world ending.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: But you are *special*, Andrew.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, a username is **not** spam.

The [user account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3159971/systematix-infotech) is not engaging in any spammy behaviour that I can see. Yes, the answers are not the highest quality and voting already reflects that, but they are on-topic and do not contain any overt promotion to qualify as spam.

Yes, the user account uses the About Me to promote the company, and the account links to their homepage URL, but such links are marked as no-follow. And the post quality is such that I'd more see this as a anti-advertisement for the company services anyway. It is not against the ToS, certainly. Take a look at [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for a user doing a much better job at using his account name to promote his company; this method of self-promotion is perfectly fine.

If you do find an account with a more overt spamming purpose (fake Gucci handbags!), flag a post for moderator attention using the 'other' link and explain your suspicions.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can tell this post links to the official PHP documentation, so I don't see how this could be spam. The only link to Systematix Infotech is in the user profile, and that is not spamming.

If the user is doing something shady that is not immediately obvious if you see the post, use the "other" flag reason and explain the issue in detail.